# How to document a controller in symfony?

Tags: symfony, phpdocumentor2

I'm trying to document my project. I want to document my controller. Before my Action I have:

```
/**
 * Description: xxx
 * @param parameters of my function Action
 * @return views of the action
 */
```

The return value here will show:

[image]

Why?

Thanks

EDIT:

A standard controller:

```
public function myControllerAction(Request $request) {

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [@return](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html) annotation expects the data type as a first argument, before the description. In your case you've specified the data type as `views` which hasn't been included with a `use` statement, so PHP assumes it belongs to the current namespace and you get `\AppBundle\Controllers\views`. The return type of a controller must be a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`. So you want:

```
@return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response description
```

or if you already have a `use` statement for Response:

```
@return Response description
```

In some cases you might want to be more specific if you are always returning a specific subclass of response, like:

- [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html)
- [JsonResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html)
- [RedirectResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html)
- [StreamedResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html)

Comment: I have add a default of my controller, all the controller have the same form of return in my application. How can I document this kind of returns?

Comment: @anubis In that case just use the response base class: `@return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`. All controllers return one of those (as does `->render`).

Comment: @anubis Yeah, that's the correct thing to have there. You can change the "description" part to whatever you want though.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't throught that the correct form!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100072/discussion-between-anubis-and-paulpro).

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the first word after `@return` is considered the type of the returned data [according to the official phpDocumentor docs](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html):

```
@return datatype description
@return datatype1|datatype2 description
```